# streaming video from database

Tags: database, servlets, video, streaming, video.js

I have a table containing videos as blob data. Im trying to stream it into browser using video tag in a webpage by writing the bytestream from blob into http response and giving the tat as a value for source in  tag. 
My code is as follows:

```
    while ( rs2.next()) {

             out.println("<h4>" + rs2.getString("caption") + "</h4>");

             out.println("<video id=\"example_video\" class=\"video-js vjs-default-    skin\" controls preload=\"none\" width=\"640\" height=\"264\""+
                         "  data-setup=\"{}\">"+
"   <source src=\"displayvideo?title=\""+  rs2.getString("caption") + "type='video/mp4'      />"+

   " <track kind=\"captions\" src=\"captions.vtt\" srclang=\"en\" label=\"English\" />"+
"  </video>");

        }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I am not viewing any `<embed src="" height="200" width="200">` tag within  tag.

Try to refer this link

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_videos.asp

to get the perfect help about the tag.

Hope its helpful!!!

Answer (score 0):

Use html for the video code first and test everything is working on your HTML+JS with regular video files.

Then work on the page that will serve videos, you might need to mimic the headers of a regular file request, you can check what are the headers of the regular file requests by doing those requests and activate firebug on Firefox or similar tool on other browsers. Check that regular video file headers and the video server page are the same on what is needed.

After that is done and working, you can then start working on something that has the functionality from the code you posted.

I can code what you need if you are hiring, let me know.

P.S. Ignore Freelancer answer, because you are working with videojs, your html code is ok